# Django Show selected data from database based on user input in html

Tags: html, django, database, input

I am a newbie.
I create restaurant system by using Django. I want to display data (table number, item, and quantity of the food) which has been inserted to database. I want to show the data based on the random id which has been generated while the customer doing the food ordering. Hence, I do not know how to do it.

Anyone can help me please

I have tried these codes, but it only shows the back button. I cannot retrieve the data based on the random id from database

here is my models.py

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    Table_No = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    Item = models.TextField()
    Qty = models.IntegerField(blank=False)
    Price = models.TextField()
    Status = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True)
    OrderId = models.TextField(max_length=100, null=True)
```

my html file:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <!--<input type="Submit" name="submit" value="See Order"/>-->
            {% for order in so1 %}
            <table width="800">
                <tr>
                    <th width="800">Table Number</th>
                    <th width="800">Item</th>
                    <th width="800">Quantity</th>
                    <th width="800">Status</th>
                    <th width="800">Order Id</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td width="800">{{ order.Table_No }}</td>
                    <td width="800">{{ order.Item }}</td>
                    <td width="800">{{ order.Qty }}</td>
                    <td width="800">{{ order.Status }}</td>
                    <td width="800">{{ order.OrderId }}</td>
                </tr>
            {% endfor %}
    <input action="action" onclick="window.history.go(-1); return false;" type="button" value="Back" />
```

my view:

```
def see_order(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        Table_No = request.POST.get("Table_No")
        Item = request.POST.get("Item")
        Qty = request.POST.get("Qty")
        Status = request.POST.get("Status")
        OrderId = request.POST.get("OrderId")
        track_order = request.POST.get('textfield', None)

        if(OrderItem.objects.get(OrderId)):
            if(OrderId==OrderId): 
                try:
                    summary = OrderItem.objects.get(OrderId=track_order)
                    so1 = OrderItem.objects.filter(Table_No=Table_No)
                    so = OrderItem.objects.filter(Item=Item)
                    so = OrderItem.objects.filter(Qty=Qty)
                    so = OrderItem.objects.filter(Status=Status)
                    so = OrderItem.objects.filter(OrderId=OrderId)
                    html = ("<H1>%s</H1>", summary)
                    return render(request, 'restaurants/see_order.html', {'so1': so1 , 'so': so})
                except OrderItem.DoesNotExist:
                    return HttpResponse("no such user")
    else:
        return render(request, 'restaurants/customer_page.html')
```

I expect the result will show the table number, item, and quantity when i input the random id. But it doesn't show anything except the back button.

Comment: Where are you inputting the ID?

Comment: I declare it as OrderId which will generate 5 random id

Comment: That wasn't what I asked. *Where* are you inputting it? How is it getting to the `see_order` view? Where are the other values (qty, item, table_no) etc being input?

Comment: what do you mean by random id? how could that be random?

Comment: @DanielRoseman i use the textfield in another html page. The customer suppose to input the random id and click the submit button, then it will show their orders

Comment: @Wils i use this code OrderId = get_random_string(length=5) to get the random id

Answer (score 0):

Your logic makes no sense.

You make lots of queries, but ignore their result - you either do nothing with the variable at all, or overwrite the existing variable with the result of the next query.

For example, you get `summary`, wrap it in "h1" tags for some reason (why aren't you doing that in the template) to get a variable called `html`, and then *completely ignore that variable*.

For the rest, you get something called `so` by filtering on `Item`, then *overwrite* that with a completely different filter based on `Qty`, then `Status`, etc.

Not to mention, `if(OrderId==OrderId)` is completely pointless.

You should remove all the useless logic. Since you want to filter by OrderId, you should just do that, and return the data to the database.

```
if request.method == "POST":
    OrderId = request.POST.get("OrderId")
    so = OrderItem.objects.filter(OrderId=OrderId)
    return render(request, 'restaurants/see_order.html', {'so': so})
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I already delete and change it to your instructions. But it still show the back button only

Comment: Your template should iterate over `so`, not `so1`.